# Using void pointers in function signarture

Tags: c

I've recently inherited some (undocumented) C code that contains several instances of this pattern:

```
void my_function(void *_foo, const void *_bar) {
    MyType *foo = (MyType *)_foo;
    MyType *bar = (MyType *)_bar;
```

I'm pretty familiar with C but I can't for the life of me figure out why the function consumes void pointers. Isn't this just going to suppress potentially helpful compiler warnings if the wrong type is passed in anywhere? Or is there a sensible method behind it that I am new to?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort and similar

Comment: Sometimes you can't specify the type. For instance when your framework accepts callbacks and user data. Note however, that the second cast is a potential cause of undefined behavior. It discards `const` qualifiers, and it's also redundant (`void*` is implicitly convertible to all pointer types).

Comment: @M.M Why does it imply a bug? It looks like a safeguard against accessing the void pointers to me. Good call on swapping it out and recompiling - I will try that.

Comment: @M.M My bad, I had a typo. The function params and local variables do not have the same name - having them the same creates a compiler error! Thanks

Comment: @DaveBensonPhillips Cool. Removed my comments now that that's sorted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the `void *` is used as an abstraction i.e. you can pass pointers of different types using `void *` to a function and later depending on appropriate conditions, you can typecast the `void *` to the correct type and use it.

Another usage could be when the calling function is in a logically separate unit like a library and doesn't have access to the correct type to which the pointer belongs. But, still the data has to pass through that function.

I used to use such abstraction mechanisms with callbacks. For Example, if I am calling a library which function which eventually calls my callback and I want some data of application in my callback, but, the library function has no use of it, then I will pass such data typecasted as `void *` to the library function and on receiving that data in the callback, I will typecast it to appropriate type and use it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: @DaveBensonPhillips, Welcome. Please accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks.